# LINUX Script que funciona en libreElec, no lo hace en Lakka... ¿por qué?

Tags: linux

Este script me funciona perfectamente en /bin/bash, en raspbian, y en /bin/sh, en libreElec:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm Favorites.txt

touch Favorites.txt
chmod 777 Favorites.txt

for tagfile in *.tag; do
  romlist="$(echo $tagfile|cut -f1 -d '.')"
  while read line; do
    title="${line/$'\r'/}"
    grep "^${title};" "${romlist}.txt" >> Favorites.txt
    echo "${tagfile}"
    echo "${title}"
    echo "${romlist}.txt"
  done < "${tagfile}"
done

wc -l Favorites.txt
```

Sin embargo en Lakka, que está basado en LibreElec, no me traslada los datos a Favorites.txt

¿Alguien sabría por qué ocurre esto y cómo solucionarlo?

Por si sirve de ayuda, aquí hay un archivo pequeñito con una carpeta con el script y los ficheros de ejemplo:

[carpeta](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13-LUJMbHDMuFzq62A8mS3jT1P8JHdasA)

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: `grep` y `wc` son programas externos (no incluidos en bash)  puede ser que los diferentes entornos no provean una implementación de los mismos

Comment: Lo más probable es que sea el dialecto `bash` de tu script,  entiendo que  `busybox` usa `sh` como interprete de comandos.

Comment: Pues debe ser algo específico de Lakka, porque en libreElec funciona perfectamente, aún no lo había probado... OpenElec ya no es parte de Lakka...

Comment: revertí tu edición, la solución no va en la misma pregunta, por favor usa la zona de respuestas debajo para colocar que hiciste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues el tema ha sido sencillo, me han dado la solución en el foro de Lakka.

Había que pasar los archivos *.tag de dos/windows a unix/linux...

Gracias a todos por el interés